# Comprehensive easy to understand resource for learning matrix decompositions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, online-resources

I am working on my thesis which is widely depended on knowledge about matrix decompositions. I have studied linear algebra with the help of YouTube videos, MITOpenCourseWare videos and Prof.Gilbert Strang's book.
Now I need a comprehensive rather easy to understand resource for studying matrix decompositions covering concepts like:

```
Smith Decomposition
Smith-McMillanDecomposition
Multicompanion Form
Hypercompanion Form and Jordan Form
Schur Decomposition
Singular Value Decomposition
Pencils and the Kronecker Canonical Form
Polar Decomposition
Additive Decompositions
...
...
Everything that is needed to know about matrix decompositions
```

Can you please help me introduce such a source?
Do you know of any course in the university where these concepts are taught?
Can I found videos of such course on the net just as I found Gilbert Strang lectures on the net?